# Android preference-headers extra parameter

Tags: android, xml, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I am building preference activity using headers. In the documentation, I saw that `extra` parameters can be specified per each `header` entry. In the code, I'd like to access those extra values when building the header list within the settings activity as follows. Note that I am doing it from the activity which overloads `onBuildHeaders` and not from the header fragment.

```
if (header.extras != null && header.extras.containsKey("someKey")) {
    ...
}
```

However, the extras parameter is always null. Is there a way for force it to be read in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your extras in your `header` like so:

```
<header android:title="Display" >
  <extra
    android:name="separator"
    android:value="true" />
</header>
```

And then retrieve the value with the following:

```java
    boolean isSeparator = false;
    Bundle extras = header.fragmentArguments;
    if (extras != null)
    {
      isSeparator = extras.containsKey("separator");
    }
```

Note that you want to use `header.fragmentArguments` instead of the `.extras` field.